# is creating an instance of a class considered as side effect or declaration in PHP Standards Recommendations?

Tags: php, language-lawyer, psr-1

is creating an instance of class considered as  side effect or declaration? how it is considered in PHP recommendation standards.

Comment: Well, does it _have_ a side effect? Declarations create new function/class names, an instantiation which assigns to a variable creates a new variable. That's generally not much different, and if it's expected what names will be created and it has no other actual side effects… then it doesn't.

Comment: well, I think that object creation can  also be perceived  as activating class just like a function which can be called with this - "()"

Comment: Sure, but if it doesn't _have any side effect_, then that's neither here nor there. Even for just "defining" something, you may be running some functions; maybe to determine what extensions are available and conditionally defining different functions or such.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with regard to PSR-1 [Basic Coding Style], [Section 2.3](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#23-side-effects):

- Neither declaring nor instantiating a class is inherently a side effect.
- Code contained in a file should only do one or the other.

Eg, this would be a "side effect rule violation" if it was in a single file:

```php
class Foo {
  // ...
}

$f = new Foo();
```

The instantiation at the end would inherently affect the state of the execution into which it was included by declaring a new variable in the local scope.

Though, for clarity, instantiating new objects during the execution of methods is fine, as these variables are contained to the object's scope. Eg:

```php
class Foo {
  protected $thing;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->thing = new Thing();
  }
}
```

The above code is fine as far as PSR-1 side-effects go, but runs afoul of more esoteric coding style conventions like Composition/Dependency Injection/SOLID/etc if you're into those things.

All that said, be aware that the term "side-effects" has different meanings depending on the context. For example: a function that modifies data outside of its local scope such as global state could be said to have side-effects, but could be written in a manner that it is not considered a side-effect in the context of PSR-1. Eg:

```php
class Foo {
  public function __construct() {
    global $foo;
    $foo = 'bar';
  }
}
```